# Is that possible to sort HashMap by Arrays.sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, hashmap

I would like to sort an array using `Arrays.sort`. I know that it should be done by `Collections.sort` but the teacher wanted use of `Arrays.sort` is that possible?  **I would like to pass comparator.**

Comment: Also you can't use collections.sort to sort a Map.

Comment: Do you want to sort map entries or values ?

Comment: You want to sort ArrayList or HashMap? The second is not possible because there's no such think as sorted HashMap

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
Arrays.sort(yourHashMap.entrySet().toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a `HashMap` *per se* because it cannot hold an order.

You can extract the key set, the entry set or the values collection to a list or array and then sort the resulting data structure.  Here's an example:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = ...
String[] orderedKeys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
Arrays.sort(orderedKeys, someStringComparator);
```

Of course, that won't affect the order of the keys/values/entries of the original `Map`.

If you want the keys in the map to be maintained in a sorted order, you need to use a `TreeMap` with a `Comparable` key or a suitable `Comparator` ... instead of a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not directly sort a Map with Collections.sort() or Arrays.sort(), but you can use a TreeMap and pass a comparator to it:

```
        Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });

    map.put(1, "1");
    map.put(0, "0");
    map.put(3, "3");
    map.put(2, "2");

    System.out.println(map);
```

This will print: {0=0, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3}
So it sorts the entries by the key.